# Fetch entries dynamically in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am using MongoDB and NodeJS. I have two files, `models.js` and `status.js`,

models.js:-

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const EntrySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    url: String,
    statuscheck: String
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Entry', EntrySchema);
```

status.js :-

```
const Entry = require('models.js');

var https = require('https');

module.exports = function getHttpsRequests () {

    https.get('https://www.google.com', function (res) {
        console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);

    }).on('error', function (e) {
        console.error(e);
    });
}
```

This is how my MongoDB data looks like,

```
[
    {
        "_id": "1",
        "url": "https://google.com/",
        "statuscheck": "200",
        "createdAt": "2018-07-13T10:20:36.695Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-07-13T10:20:36.695Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "2",
        "url": "https://facebook.com/",
        "statuscheck": "200",
        "createdAt": "2018-07-13T10:21:20.699Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-07-13T10:21:20.699Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "3",
        "url": "https://wikipedia.com/",
        "statuscheck": "200",
        "createdAt": "2018-07-13T10:21:27.270Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-07-13T10:21:27.270Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "4",
        "url": "https://twitter.com/",
        "statuscheck": "200",
        "createdAt": "2018-07-13T10:23:12.271Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-07-13T10:23:12.271Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5",
        "url": "https://ebay.com/",
        "statuscheck": "200",
        "createdAt": "2018-07-13T10:23:23.891Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-07-13T10:23:23.891Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

In the status.js , I am manually checking the URL (by hardcoding google.com ). In this line,

```
https.get('https://www.google.com', function (res) {
```

I am trying to fetch the entries from Entry and put URL dynamically (URL s those are present in the MongoDB data) in a for loop way. That means, it should check for all the URLs present instead of just `google.com`

One more thing, I am trying to do is update the `statuscheck` key-value dynamically for that particular `url`. Every time, it checks for a URL, it will also update the `statuscheck` value in the database.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: In the status.js , I am manually checking the URL (by hardcoding google.com ). I am trying to fetch the entries from Entry and put url dynamically (url s those are present in the data) in a for loop.

One more thing, I am trying to do is update the statuscheck key value dynamically for that particular url. Everytime, it checks for a url , it will also update the statuscheck value.

Comment: I have updated the question. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use async npm : https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html

request npm : https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

Entry.find({ }) will return array ....then we have to loop through each entry , and make http get request ....so we are using async npm module for `each` loop that runs asyncronously and make http calls.

```
var async=require('async');
const Entry = require('models.js');
var https = require('https');
var request = require('request');

module.exports = function getHttpsRequests () {

    Entry.find({},function(err,entrys){
      console.log(err);
      if(!err && entrys){

         async.each(entrys,function(entry,callback){


           request(entry.url, function (error, response, body) {
            console.log('error:', error); 
            console.log('statusCode:',response.statusCode); 
            entry.statusCode=res.statusCode;
            entry.save();
            callback();
            });


         },function (error) {

         });

      }
    });

}
```

Comment: It is giving me error, 
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1031:13)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1052:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1195:14)
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 443 }

Comment: @DineshAhuja , added two console.log , please check what r you getting in that console.log

Comment: It is giving the right entry list. console.error(e) is giving
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1031:13)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1052:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1195:14)
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 443 }

Comment: console.log(entry) is returning the all the entries all at once and I think problem is here entry.url ?

Comment: We have to search in a loop within the entry. Like, if I use entry[0].url , it works perfectly

Comment: @DineshAhuja `Entry.find({},function(err,entry){` will return all entries. You need to iterate over data. Look into an answer that I have posted.

Comment: One issue is, it is giving me the status code 301 while looping. If I do it for a single entry without looping then it is returning expected 200

Comment: so, if I use google.com instead of entry.url then it is returning 200. When I am using entry.url , it is returning 301

Comment: 301 redirect means that the page has permanently moved to a new location.

Comment: But, if I use the hardcoded url then it is returning 200

Comment: @DineshAhuja , please try with request npm , console log status code

Answer (score 0):

Structure your code into multiple layers so at least you have a clear idea.

Your DAO should be:

```
const Entry = require('models.js');

function getAll(callback){
   Entry.find({}).exec(function (err, data) {
      callback(err, data);
   });
}


function update(id, status, callback){
   Entry.findOneAndUpdate({
     _id: id
   }, {
      $push: {statuscheck: status}
   }).exec(function(err, update){
      console.log(update);
      callback(err, update);
   });
}
```

Your for loop should be under status.js:

```
DAO.getAll(function(err, data){
    for(var i =0; i< data.length; i++){
        checkAndUpdate(data[i].url, data[i].id);
    }

});

// This is seperate function to prevent "i" value to be overridden as your dependent on third party.
function checkAndUpdate(url, id){
    https.get(url, function (res) {
        DAO.update(id, res.statusCode, function(err, data){
            console.log("updated");
        });
    }).on('error', function (e) {
        console.error(e);
    });
}
```